# Using jQuery Resizable to control Margin instead of Size

Tags: jquery, margin, resizable

Sample: https://codepen.io/taterjuice/pen/aMvXwd

jQuery Resizable: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

How can I use jquery Resizable to control the margin around an element, rather than it's width and height?

```
 $(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 
// colResizable 1.6 - a jQuery plugin by Alvaro Prieto Lauroba http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/